# Invalid Signature - iTunes Connect Nightmare

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my third app to the app store. However apple keep rejecting it saying:

**Invalid Signature** - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.

As per the attached screenshot you can see i have done everything as i should? Does anyone know what else i can try????[image]

Comment: Is `What Move Release` an iTunes distribution certificate, not a Ad Hoc distribution certificate yes?

Comment: hi rich, yes it is an iTunes distribution certificate.. thats why I'm going crazy. lol

Comment: manually change the code signing identity from automatic to your certificate.

Comment: i've tried that as well and it still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @nobbsy and when you distribute for iTunes via Xcode you select the correct profile (its the only screen you haven't shown you see)?

Comment: @Rich yes i select the same profile, its the only one it lets me select anyway lol

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you follow the instructions at the end of error message "was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target", also try re-generating (just edit and then download) the profile again and remove the old one.

Comment: the only bit that doesn't make sense to me is "was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target" as all i know is you select iOS device, then product, archive, then upload it...

Comment: I would do as Rich suggested. Xcode goes mad from time to time...

Comment: Perhaps a file is being included in your IPA that doesn't need to be included and Apple is now rejecting. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30793765/503821

Answer (score 0):

By the way you're explaining this(The picture won't load for me), your app ID you have put down in xcode, and the app ID you have put down in the Apple Developer webpage need to be the same. To get to the Apple Developer webpage to see this, go to Apple Developer Member Center -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers. To find the identifier in xcode, you need to go into the build settings above all the file folders.