# Invalid Signature - Code object is not signed at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

Im able to submit my app through Xcode 6.3.2 perfectly fine. Validation and analyzing pass perfectly. Once it successfully submits to the app store though I get an email from Apple:

"Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected: 
Invalid Signature - Code object is not signed at all. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html 
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary."

I have tried redownloading the distribution cert, regenerating the distribution provisioning profile, added "--deep" to the code signing "Other Code Signing Flags." I even checked the bundle name etc, everthing is alpha numeric. I was able to submit fine on May 22nd, now on June 3rd everything breaks.

Doesnt make any sense, any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE & SOLUTION:**

While I don't have a good explanation of why this suddenly has happened within the last week, I finally found a solution this morning.

I started with a new project and submitted to the app store with nothing but the identifier and correct version and build numbers, which processed fine. After that I started piecing in any assets that wasnt my own code until I got the "Invalid Binary" email. I narrowed it down to the Hockey App SDK (embedded framework) which was causing the issue and not even being used anymore so I removed it from the project (problem solved). The disturbing part is that nothing fails on my end during validation or submission and according to github this directory and content hasn't changed in a year, which leads me to believe something changed server side at Apple.

I did see a lot of posts via google saying that frameworks needed signed etc and when using Xcode 6 and iOS 8 it seems to be the standard which is why I assumed it might be something along these lines.

Im not sure how helpful this is as I was building for iOS and this article is in reference to Mac, but HockeyApp explains in order to distribute to the app store you need to sign the framework with your own identity here:

http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/hockeyapp-for-mac-os-x

If anyone has anymore technical notes on this or why this suddenly changed Id love to understand this better.

Comment: Same problem here with Ionic and Cordova. Was your distribution profile also invalid?

Comment: At the Apple Development forums I see that there are more people facing to the same problem. This could be a problem at Itunes Connect.

Comment: Same problem here with Ionic and Cordova - and i am not using any hockey app.  Very very very frustrating..

Comment: @schmoopy For ionic, some .sh files were causing all that trouble. I solved it after deleting them. Here's where I got this solution: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-ion-swipe-cards/issues/31#issuecomment-101645762

Comment: @ahmed - thank you.  I ended up resolving by removing all www/lib and adding back only needed js/css -- I didn't have any sh files other than one for the build which wasn't causing an issue

Answer (score 2):

I've checked a variety of places and there seem to be several things that are now being rejected by iTunes Connect. The solution is typically to remove the offending resource from the Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources (as @azizus mentions). Unfortunately Apple doesn't tell you what file causes this issue with your builds so you have to go hunt for yourself. Here are some items that I've found that will do it:

- Shell scripts (Look for .sh files, though they could have a different
  extension)
- Also, look out for files that are listed as executable, when they
  shouldn't be. Those might be a good place to look for shell scripts
  that you might have missed.
- Frameworks (Framework bundles, even .a or .o files - you
  don't need them as they will get compiled into the executable binary)
- DocSets (I don't know why, but I found that the HockeyApp SDK
  includes a DocSet bundle which was the cause in my experience)
- Sometimes this might also happen due to some weird entitlements
  issue. The entitlements you have may not match up with the App in the
  provisioning portal.
- Look out for invalid characters in your app name or file names (like
  wildcard characters)

This is a pretty broad list, something I did to help in the search is build an archive and then show the contents of the .app in the archive using finder, sorting by file type. The strange thing is that these files actually exist in the _CodeSignature/CodeResources file.

My own theory on why this is happening is that Apple made some changes (or is making some changes) because of Extensions and WatchKit apps. Essentially, you are including a couple of binaries in the packaged IPA (phone app, extension, watch app). They probably want to make sure you're not including something else that could potentially be executed. Unfortunately, the error message is too vague (really it's incorrect) for most.

Comment: Most helpful checklist.  I also had a stray plist file, and a mobileprovision file which seem to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

This took me 3 days to debug.

In the end it was due to an external framework I created (lets call it X) that I was importing via carthage. X had its own dependencies that it was importing via carthage as well. In order to link these frameworks it had a path in the build settings called `Framework Search Paths` set to the location of the frameworks. For some reason it was this flag in this framework that was causing the problem specified in the questions. I eventually imported X's dependencies with Git submodules so that I didn't have to set the `Framework Search Paths` flag. I the exported the framework and manually added it to my project I was submitting to the AppStore. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this when I 'create folder references' for my resources folder as opposed to 'create groups' when adding in.

Comment: better as a comment

Comment: are you creating a safari extension? is this specific to the Resources/ folder?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted HockeyApp and they suggested not to add the SDK to app bundle. So I navigated to Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and removed HockeySDKResources.bundle from  there. iTunes Connect accepted my binary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a info.plist duplicated that was not used. (it wasn't easy find out the problem). I removed almost all the files of my project until remove this one and.. it worked

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the value for Code Sign Resource Rules Path in each target resolved the issue.